# Can i use a set or List in this example?

Tags: java, hibernate, list, collections

```
public class Student implements java.io.Serializable {

private long studentId;
private String studentName;
private Set<Course> courses = new HashSet<Course>(0);

public Student() {
}

public Student(String studentName) {
    this.studentName = studentName;
}

public Student(String studentName, Set<Course> courses) {
    this.studentName = studentName;
    this.courses = courses;
}

public long getStudentId() {
    return this.studentId;
}

public void setStudentId(long studentId) {
    this.studentId = studentId;
}

public String getStudentName() {
    return this.studentName;
}

public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
    this.studentName = studentName;
}

public Set<Course> getCourses() {
    return this.courses;
}

public void setCourses(Set<Course> courses) {
    this.courses = courses;
}
```

}

Here they are using Hashset to get the courses. My doubt is can i use a list to get the
courses here. I read in internet that list get the vaues in a specified order and allows
duplicates inside the list. whereas in set it doesnt have any order and wont allow
duplicates. I want to know where i should uses sets and lists? Can anyone suggest?

Comment: What you read on the net is basically right. You may learn more e.g. from [the Java Tutorials on Collections](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html).

Comment: @Péter Török thanks for this nice tutorial

Comment: if i get a collection using <address>
private Address studentAddress;
What does this mean? it is not a set it is another class addresss. How can i use this.What is this use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It feels like you answered your own question already.  If you need a Collection of items, and you want the collection of items to have no duplicates, use a Set.  You can use a [SortedSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) to impose ordering.

If your collection is allowed to have duplicates, then you can use a List.  I think in your example, a Set works since a student would probably never take the same course twice.

Comment: @SB if i get a collection using <address>
private Address studentAddress;
What does this mean? it is not a set it is another class addresss. How can i use this.What is this use?

Comment: Is it Collection<Address> or Set<Address> or is just Address studentAddress?  If it's `private Address studentAddress` then you're just getting an Address object back.  If it's Set<Address> then it's a Set of these Address objects, and if it's a Collection<Address> then it's just some collection (could be Set or List) and you're not supposed to care about the underlying implementation - just that it's a number of Address objects.

Comment: @SB thanks i understood that i am using class name for getting objects. What is that "it's a number of Address objects" i cant get it.

Comment: When I say it's a number of Address objects, I mean it's a bunch of Address objects in some kind of container (or Collection as it's called in Java) - this could be either a List, or Set, or some other container.  I highly suggest reading the tutorial posted in the comments of the question.  It's a good read, and I think you would benefit from it.

Answer (score 3):

The fundamental difference between `List` and `Set` is (as you said) that `Set` does not allow duplicates, while `List` does. So in your case a `Set` is more appropriate, since a student should not be able to enroll in course twice. Actually, he *should* be able, but on in the same semester. So you may have each student have a set of `CourseEnrollment` objects, rather than `Course` objects.

Note that preserving order is not impossible for a `Set` - there are implementations (like `LinkedHashSet`) that preserve the order of elements, and other, like `TreeSet`, which keep to elements sorted.

Comment: if i get a collection using <address>
private Address studentAddress;
What does this mean? it is not a set it is another class addresss. How can i use this.What is this use?